# Create two Reactjs apps in the same project by sharing node_modules

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a project that has two Apps, one for the administrative area and one for the user.

Within the project there are the routes / admin and / user, everything works correctly, in the / src folder there is a components folder that I share between the two areas.

When I do the build to publish the project, it creates the files that on average is 5MB, if I remove all the administrative area and do the build again the size drops to 2MB.

Is it possible to build the separate areas in some way?

Because if I do it this way \ admin will have 3MB and \ user will have 2MB and consequently they will load faster but, I would not want to miss sharing the components of the same project.

Today I work on other projects similar to this one creating two separate apps, but when it comes to sharing the components that are the same, it's hard to copy everything again to update.

I use the create-react-app